Duplicating slides on powerpoint using office-js API
I have spent a lot of time investigating this issue. I tried capturing all the shapes of the selected slide and pasting it over to the intended slide. My code and the one i got from script lab works for very simple slides but it breaks as soon as you try to access any properties from the newly created shape.
export async function duplicateSelectedSlide () {
  // Deleting selected slide.
  try {
    await PowerPoint.run(async (context) => {
      // Add new slide.
      await addnewSlide();
      await context.sync();

      console.log("Slide has been successfully added");
      // Get selected slide.

      const slide = context.presentation.getSelectedSlides().getItemAt(0);
      await context.sync();
      
      console.log("slides have been selected successfully");

      // console.log("Slide has been successfully loaded ", slide);

      // Get all the shapes from selected slides.
      slide.load("shapes");
      await context.sync();
      const shapes = slide.shapes;
      
      // console.log("Slide shapes have been loaded ", shapes);
      shapes.load("items");
      await context.sync();

      // select the last slide based on the slideId.
      const slides = context.presentation.slides;
      slides.load("items");
      await context.sync();

      const slideIds = slides.items.map(slide => slide.id);

      const lastSlide = slides.getItemAt(slideIds.length - 1);
      lastSlide.load("shapes");
      await context.sync();

      // Add the shapes to the new slide.
      for ( const shape of shapes.items ){
        // load the shape properties.
        shape.load("fill/height/id/left/lineFormat/name/tags/textFrame/top/type/width");

        // let newShape;
        // insert shapes
        if (shape.textFrame){
          // load the properties of the textFrame
          shape.textFrame.load("textRange");
          shape.textFrame.textRange.load("text/font");
          await context.sync();
          console.log("the text located inside the shape is ", shape.textFrame.textRange.text);
          // if textFrame exists then add textBox with the required properties.
          const newShape = lastSlide.shapes.addTextBox(shape.textFrame.textRange.text);

          newShape.height = shape.height;
          newShape.left = shape.left;
          newShape.top = shape.top;
          newShape.width = shape.width;

          // // load the fontsize from the shape
          shape.textFrame.textRange.font.load("size");
          await context.sync();

          console.log("the font size of the text is ", shape.textFrame.textRange.font.size);

          // If I uncomment the following lines to access any property of newShape, i get an error.

          // newShape.load("textFrame");
          // await context.sync();

          // newShape.textFrame.load("textRange");
          // await context.sync();

          // newShape.textFrame.textRange.load("font");
          // await context.sync();

          // newShape.textFrame.textRange.font.load("size");
          // await context.sync();


          // newShape.textFrame.textRange.font.size = shape.textFrame.textRange.font.size;
          await context.sync();
        }
      }
    })
  } catch ( error ){
    console.log("Error occured : ", error);
  }
}

the error is
Error occured :  RichApi.Error: InvalidParam passed to GetItem(id)
    at new n (powerpoint-web-16.00.js:26:319642)
    at r.processRequestExecutorResponseMessage (powerpoint-web-16.00.js:26:384259)
    at powerpoint-web-16.00.js:26:382321

From the experience i had, i wanted to know if i can confidently conclude there is no way of duplicating a slide whatsoever using office.js ? Another post talks about this being a microsoft error.
Has anyone faced this kind of issue and can tell me if they were able to duplicate a slide or did anything else ??
